# Finding the Elements of $D_5$

Tags: group-theory

I'm using [this](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/section-dihedral-groups.html) online textbook to learn group theory. For one of the exercises, I'm supposed to list all of the elements of $D_5$. I understand that I have to find all the products of $r$ and $s$, where $$ r^n = 1$$ $$ s^2 = 1$$ $$ srs = r^{-1}$$ And I also know that there are $2 \times 5=10$ such elements in total. My guess is that some of these elements are (12345)
(13524)
(14253)
(15432) and (1), stemming from the first rule. But I'm not exactly sure how to get the other elements from the two remaining rules. Any help on this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with composition of permutations? An example:
Suppose you have a permutation $(1\ 3\ 5)$ and one that is $(1\ 3)$. What would $(1\ 3\ 5)(1\ 3)$ look like? A way to compute the resulting permutation is to take all elements and look where they are sent to from right to left. We see:

- $1$ is sent to $3$ by $(1\ 3)$ and *then* $3$ is sent to $5$ by $(1\ 3\ 5)$; so $1$ is sent to $5$ in the result.
- $5$ is sent to itself by $(1\ 3)$ as it does not appear in it. By $(1\ 3 \ 5)$ it will be sent to $1$; so $5$ is sent to $1$.
- $3$ is sent to $1$ by $(1\ 3)$ and *then* $1$ is sent to $3$ again by $(1\ 3\ 5)$; in the end $3$ will thus be sent to itself.

If you combine these 3 facts, you can write the resulting permutation as $(1\ 5)(3)$ or simply $(1\ 5)$.

Now, think of the groups $D_n$ in actual shapes. A rotation $r$ will typically be $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$ as you will turn every point of the shape to the next one (try to visualize a pentagon). A mirroring will put points to their opposites, so for instance $s=(1)(2\ 5)(3\ 4)$ (draw out a pentagon and number the corners $1$-$5$)

Now try to compute $r,r^2(=rr),\dots,r^4$ and $sr,sr^2\dots sr^4$. Along with $id=r^5=s^2$ and $s$ you will indeed have the $10$ elements you're looking for!

**Note:**

You can interpret the group is indeed given by $id,r^i,sr^i$ by looking at real-life geometric shapes. We know it shall contain $4$ rotations and $5$ mirrorings (each reflection taken from each corner of the shape). However, all reflections can be found by only mirroring once and then turning a set amount of times.

Consider a necklace with 5 marbles on a table. The top of the marbles are colored black and the bottom are colored white. Mirroring will be turning the necklace over through an axis of 2 marbles. It doesn't matter in which way you mirror it, if you flip it over all the marbles will show white. Therefore, you can flip it any way you like and then rotate to get the desired result; hence $sr^i$ will cover all the reflections.